# Поиск функции через шаблонный аргумент аргумента

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, language-lawyer

```
namespace A {
    struct A {};
    void call_foo(void (*f)()) {
        f();
    }
}

template<class T>
void f();

int main() {
    call_foo(f<A::A>);
}
```

Является ли этот код валидным и почему? Компиляторы имеют [разногласия](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:18,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:18,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:18,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:18,startLineNumber:8),source:%27namespace+A+%7B%0A++++struct+A+%7B%7D%3B%0A++++void+call_foo(void+(*f)())+%7B%0A++++++++f()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3Cclass+T%3E%0Avoid+f()%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++call_foo(f%3CA::A%3E)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:clang_trunk,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:gsnapshot,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/10%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) на этот счёт (`gcc` и `msvc` компилируют его, в то время как `clang` - нет).

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'call_foo'; did you mean
> 'A::call_foo'?

Comment: Если написать еще одну такую функцию в безымянном пространстве имен, то какая из них должна вызываться, если разрешить такой поиск?  Не знаю какой компилятор это пропускает, но если пропускает _ это не законная помощь вам со стороны  умного  и  доброго компилятора.

Answer (score 2):

Кажется что Clang прав, код не должен компилироваться.

Открываем [`[basic.lookup.argdep]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#3). Пишут, что при ADL для шаблонов классов учитываются шаблонные аргументы. Про шаблоны функций ничего не написано, значит их шаблонные аргументы не учитываются.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, логика немного другая. Когда в шаблон класса подставляются аргументы шаблона, шаблон класса становится классом (специализацией шаблона), и к нему применяется пункт 3.2, в котором среди ассоциируемых типов перечислены аргументы шаблона. Когда то же самое происходит с шаблоном функции, к полученной функции  применяется пункт 3.5, где среди ассоциируемых типов аргументы шаблона не указаны, указаны только типы аргументов и возвращаемого значения самой функции, а не ее шаблона, а также типы, ассоциируемые с аргументами и возвращаемым значением

Comment: @Ariox Мне кажется я сказал то же самое, только более простыми словами. :)

Comment: кажется да, **clang** прав. правильно надо было добавить `using A :: call_foo ;` Все же терпят ошибку `cout << ..` неопределён, и сразу добавляют **using**.